# Moving an object continuously when left or right key is pressed

Tags: c#, unity

I want the object to move continuously as long as key is pressed to left when left arrow is pressed and to right when right arrow is pressed.
 Instead of moving continuously it moves first time and then never moves again.What seems wrong with this code?

```
void Update()
{
    if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftArrow))
                {
                    var _speedleft = 0.2f;
                    this.transform.position = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * _speedleft *Time.deltaTime, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
                }

                if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.RightArrow)) 
                {   var _speedright = 0.2f;
                    this.transform.position = new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * _speedright *Time.deltaTime, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
                }
}
```

Comment: why exactly the downvote?

Comment: No idea, except this is not very bright question. Just set a bool flag(check key press change) and always move if the bool is true in update method(dont check key press now).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are assigning the same position at every frame when the related key is pressed. Adding the value should solve the problem.

```
this.transform.position += new Vector3 (Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal") * _speedright *Time.deltaTime, this.transform.position.y, this.transform.position.z);
```

Comment: This is correct, that you need to add to the position, although you can't just += the position.

Comment: So the accepted answer doesn't have correct syntax and doesn't work at all. Interesting.